# why QuickBooks.php is blank?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have downloaded the QuickBooks php framework from https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164&enterthread=y. I have configured the database. But for some reason when I visit the QuickBooks.php the page is blank. Its not even generating any error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to visit the QuickBooks.php file in a browser.

Read the documentation in the docs/ folder (look for example_server.php or example_web_connector.php) and follow the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit Quick-start Guide](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector_quickstart)

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking too. I have seen some the example and I found a way to make it work. Thanks for your response....